# How to specify a branch of a local git repository in my pubspec.yaml configuration?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Given I have a Dart/Flutter project that is using local a package (which is a git repository), how can I specify a branch for that local package? For example I have the following development directory:

```
.
├── my_application
└── my_package
```

In my `my_package` I have a branch called `new-functionality`. I want to use the `new-functionality` branch *without* doing a git-checkout in the repository.

In `my_application/pubspec.yaml`, I would like to specify that local package and branch  along the lines of this:

```yaml
my_package:
  git:
    url: ../my_package # I know this is not valid
    ref: new-functionality
```

In the [Dart/Flutter Package Dependency documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages) I couldn't find any way to achieve this with a git repository on my local machine.

Can I specify a branch for that local git repository package in my project's `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `file://` URL to refer to a local Git repository.  For example:

```yaml
dependencies:
  my_package:
    git:
      url: file:///home/Apealed/git/my_package
      ref: new-functionality
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without the file prefix and instead use directory relative access:

```
dependencies:
  your_package:
    git: ../your_package_folder
```

Comment: Do this method still allow you to specify a commit?

Comment: @APEALED Actually it does. `git: STRING` is just shorthand syntax for `git: url: STRING`, so you can still specify a `git: ref:` key if you want.  In other words, the `file://` prefix in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69412628/) can just be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, @jamesdlin